# Xcode - Swift SpriteKit: SKTileMapNode with a "physics gap"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

I am playing around with SpriteKit and the TileMapNode and i've got an annoying problem.

That's how it should look like.
[image]

That's how its actually looking in the simulator/device.

[image]

The white spaces are terrible and i have no idea, how to get rid of them.
My Tiles are about 70x70 in the "Sprite Atlas - Part" of the assets, i've configured my tilemapnode with a scale of 0.5 and tile size of 70x70.

While testing some cases, i figured out that this part of code triggers the error, but i have no idea, what could be wrong. Changing the `SKPhysicsBody` size to a smaller one, did not helped.

```
guard let tilemap = childNode(withName: "LevelGround") as? SKTileMapNode else { return }            
let tileSize = tilemap.tileSize
        let halfWidth = CGFloat(tilemap.numberOfColumns) / 2.0 * tileSize.width
        let halfHeight = CGFloat(tilemap.numberOfRows) / 2.0 * tileSize.height
        for row in 0..<tilemap.numberOfRows {
            for col in 0..<tilemap.numberOfColumns {
                if tilemap.tileDefinition(atColumn: col, row: row) != nil {
                    let x = CGFloat(col) * tileSize.width - halfWidth
                    let y = CGFloat(row) * tileSize.height - halfHeight
                    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tileSize.width, height: tileSize.height)
                    let tileNode = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)
                    tileNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                    tileNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 70, height: 70), center: CGPoint(x: tileSize.width / 2.0, y: tileSize.height / 2.0))
                    tileNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
                    tileNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 2
                    tileNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
                    tileNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2 | 1
                    tileNode.name = "Ground"
                    tilemap.addChild(tileNode)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: where your scene is loaded (usually from the viewController). set showPhysics to true. It should show you where your alignments are off.

Answer (score 0):

```
tileNode.strokeColor = .clear
```

solved the problem

Update:
problem not solved... just moved :/

When checking, if ground & player are in contact, every new tile the status is switching between "contact" and "no contact". 
When using a cube instead a circle, the cube begins to rotate. It seems, the corner of the cube get's stuck at the minimal space between the tiles.